# Error when using variadic template to pass arguments in Event-base system

Tags: c++, templates

**Main.cpp**

```
GameObject o;
ISubscriber *sub = new Subscriber<GameObject, int, int, int>();
static_cast<Subscriber<GameObject, int, int, int>*>(sub)->gameObject = &o;
static_cast<Subscriber<GameObject, int, int, int>*>(sub)->gameObjectFunction = &(GameObject::Sum);

//this next line is one that gives error
cout << (static_cast<Subscriber<GameObject, int, int, int>*>(sub)->CallFunction)(2,5);
```

**Subscriber.h**

```
template<class ObjectClass, class ReturnType, class ...Params>
class Subscriber : public ISubscriber
{
public:
    ObjectClass *gameObject;
    ReturnType(ObjectClass::*gameObjectFunction)(Params...);
public:     
    returnType  CallFunction(Params...) { (gameObject->*gameObjectFunction)(Params...); };

    Subscriber();
    ~Subscriber();
};
```

**GameObject.h**

```
class GameObject
{
public:
   int Sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; };    
public:
    GameObject();
    GameObject(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h);
    virtual ~GameObject();
};
```

**ERROR** : `type 'int' unexpected`

So what I'm doing is event system where i could call event that has list of "ISubscriber*" objects where each "Subscriber" holds "Object*" and pointer to function in that "Object*". "ISubscriber" does nothin besides being parent class of "Subscriber" so I can store them in vector as pointers

When creating new Subscriber we pass type of object, return type for function pointer, and any number of arguments. I did this because when deciding what function my "gameObjectFunction*" should point to we can pass any return type and any number of arguments, so we can point at any function.

Everything works fine until I need to use variadic template in last line of "Main.cpp" and it says that "type int unexpected" event if I pass "int,int" as variadic template arguments.

Also any memory leaks, static/dynamic casts tips are not part of my question and there might be some spelling mistakes since it took me 10 minutes to paste code here in format that looks humanly readable.

Comment: I corrected some obvious mistakes, but your code works when compiling with clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56278282b940b973

Comment: There is no return statement in `CallFunction`'s body. Also what happens for boundary cases such as when `ReturnType` is `void`?

Comment: m.s. Yea I forgot to write that, thanks man. Rerito missing return is what actually solve my problem so thanks man, can't believe i forgot that xD.